# iPad - touchStart() event blocked by div text

Tags: javascript, ios, dom, dom-events, touch-event

I have a div which triggers a `touchStart` event:

```
<div class="button" ontouchstart="touchStart(event)"> button</div>
```

When my finger lands on the text button inside the div the event is not triggered, anywhere else on the surface of div event is triggered, how can I make it trigger when I touch the text as well?

Answer (score 1):

if you know the size of the div, then you can add a transparent div above your text with the ontouchstart event.

```
<div class="buttoncontainer">
    <div class="button"> button</div>
    <div  ontouchstart="touchStart(event)" class="somethingrelative"></div>
</div>
```

where the buttoncontainer and somethingrelative assist in the positioning.

Answer (score 0):

You can also put the text inside another element, for example a span, and make it unreactive to events with:

```
.button span {  
    pointer-events: none;
}
```